# Sharing of article using facebook api doesnt work properly

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Hi I'm trying to develop a site that has capabilities to share articles from my site to facebook. 
[image]

The 1st article can be shared without any problem but the problem is if 
[image]
And if I choose to share the 2nd article it doesn't display that article but instead it posts the index page of my site.
[image]

I tried searching for articles/tutorials that has the same concept on what I had on mind but so far no luck at all can someone please help me
Here is how I assigned my `data`

```
<i class="fa fa-facebook fbs" data-fbshare<?=$i?>="<?=siteDomain?>?pv=<?=$row['email']?>"></i>
```

NOTE:
`$i` is a counter using `foreach`

here is my javascript code

```
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId      : 'I REMOVED MY APP ID',
          xfbml      : true,
          version    : 'v2.3'
        });

      $(".fbs").each(function(i,obj){

        $(this).addClass("fbss"+ i );

        $(".fbss"+i).on("click",function(){
            var sharedJob = $(this).data('fbshare'+i);

        FB.ui({
          method: 'share',
          href: sharedJob,
        }, function(response){}); 

      });
     });
       };
(function(d, s, id){
         var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
         if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
         js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
         js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
         fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
       }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

I tried using alert to check if its fetching the correct data and yes its fetching the data correctly.
Please Help I'm new to using facebook api :(

Comment: Check your article URLs using the debug tool: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Comment: @CBroe ok I did what you said about checking it and its giving me the same result as what I have posted. I still dont get where am I going wrong on this script

Comment: Well then show a live example of the page where the share goes wrong please.

Comment: Never Mind I think I found where I went wrong I'll post my own answer tom since I'm not infront of my laptop.. its thanks to your suggestion that I check it using the debug tool of facebook